# How to generate test overview in Frisby

Tags: jasmine-node, frisby.js

As mentioned in frisby official document (http://frisbyjs.com/) , I am using --junitreport something like following

```
 jasmine-node ./demo/validation_spec.js/ --junitreport --output
   C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\script/Reports
```

which is generating 15 xml files. As I am calling 15 time post using for loop. File contains data like following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<testsuites>
<testsuite name="Frisby Test:blank action    " errors="0" tests="1" failures="0" time="0.284" timestamp="2017-03-21T13:55:15">
  <testcase classname="Frisby Test: blank action    " name="
    [ POST https://localhost:8443/api/v2/settings/pointwise ]" time="0.282"></testcase>
</testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

so my difficulty is that I need to read each and every file to check if tests is pass or not. I want some kind of overview page like http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-report-plugin/surefire-report.html

which contain information how many test passed, fail etc. Is it possible to get that.